# Tableau: Previous_Value For Strings

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to tableau.
Just recently, I have encountered a problem regarding getting a string value from the previous row
I tried using Previous_Value function but it does not work. :<
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dulYD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of previous value which could be tricky when dealing with partitions, you may use the LookUp function

> Returns the value of the expression in a target row, specified as a relative offset from the current row. Use FIRST() +n and LAST() -n as part of your offset definition for a target relative to the first/last rows in the partition. If offset is omitted, the row to compare to can be set on the field menu. This function returns NULL if the target row cannot be determined.

You can create a calculated field **Order ID  Lookup - 1**:

```
LOOKUP(max([Order ID]),-1)
```

Remember that Lookup requires an aggregate value as first argoment (in my example you can use either min, max, etc...) followed by the offset you need (in this example it's 1 for previous record).

Once you have your previous value, you can create another calculated field **Check**:

```
if max([Order ID]) = [Order ID  Lookup - 1]
then '='
else '!='
end
```

Since Lookup needs an aggregate function, you should "wrap" your Order ID with an aggregation function as well in order to compare those 2 values.

Here's the final result:

[image]